# Emergency countdown missing

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

When one is the target of an emergency there was a countdown telling you how you're doing. Im missing this info after playing the first time after some weeks. Did it get removed by an update? Can I find it at a different place?

Comment: Are you sure that the emergency succeeded? The vote actually passed and there's an emergency in play?

Comment: I am sure - I was the target, so the emergency already was a fact when I learnt of it. And after 30 rounds I lost the emergency. (In the meantime there were more occurences of this issue - also some where I participated in the emergency - also no countdown.)

Comment: And you're saying there's no visible countdown/info bar underneath your other trackers such as science/culture?

Comment: @n_plum Exactly. There used to be an info panel saying something like "Athens believing in Shintoism for 16 of 30 rounds". This is gone since a few weeks.

Comment: Yeah not sure why it wouldn't be there otherwise, hadn't heard of a change being made although I know I've received updates for the game over the past few weeks, maybe just make sure your game is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a few days the countdown is back again.

[image]